# Regular expression to pull db table names from .sql files

Tags: regex

I'm looking to search my directory of sql queries and for the most prevalent database tables in all of the files.  To do so, I'm hoping to use `grep` to isolate these names but I can't quite figure out the regular expression to pull just the table names.

I figure in order to isolate the tables, I'm looking for the string of text after the words ***FROM*** or ***JOIN***.

I hoping folks can help me build off of this, but currently my grep statements are just finding the occurrences of these words, but how do I pull the string directly proceeding these keywords?

```
grep -R "FROM" | grep -R  "JOIN"
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could add in a part of an (example) file. We can't read your mind, y'know.

Comment: And, that won't work. The first `grep` has no input other than STDIN, which it ignores, and produces no output for the (ignored) input of the second `grep`.  Read http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

I pulled some sample queries from Google and made a couple sql files with the following data in them for example purposes:

**file1.sql**

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
INTO CustomersOrderBackup2013
FROM CustomersOriginal
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID;
```

**file2.sql**

```
-- Dumping data for table `user_details`
INSERT INTO `user_details` (`user_id`, `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `gender`, `password`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'rogers63', 'david', 'john', 'Female', 'e6a33eee180b07e563d74fee8c2c66b8', 1);
```

---

The first thing you're looking for is the OR operator for grep:

```
$ grep 'INTO\|FROM\|JOIN' *.sql
file1.sql:FROM Orders
file1.sql:INNER JOIN Customers
file1.sql:INTO CustomersOrderBackup2013
file1.sql:FROM CustomersOriginal
file1.sql:LEFT JOIN Orders
file2.sql:INSERT INTO `user_details` (`user_id`, `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `gender`, `password`, `status`) VALUES
```

That will get the entire lines from the original files. Next let's use *sed* to pull out the table names:

```
$ grep 'INTO\|FROM\|JOIN' *.sql | sed -r 's/.*?(FROM|INTO|JOIN)\s`?([^` ]*).*/\2/g'
Orders
Customers
CustomersOrderBackup2013
CustomersOriginal
Orders
user_details
```

Finally, let's eliminate duplicate tables:

```
$ grep 'INTO\|FROM\|JOIN' *.sql | sed -r 's/.*?(FROM|INTO|JOIN)\s`?([^` ]*).*/\2/g' | sort -u
Customers
CustomersOrderBackup2013
CustomersOriginal
Orders
user_details
```